# Javascript image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover, onmouseout

Javascript is being used to make a neat log-out button. It works almost perfectly except I cannot figure out how to attach a line to the 'span' so it also edits the image because the code uses a self variable. How can I get the image to be used in script attached to the span in the link so the image changes regardless if I am hovering over the link or the image. I have tried to use a few solutions but nothing either worked the way I wanted it to or not at all. JQuery is fine for a solution as well. I am very ignorant as far as Javascript/JQuery goes as most of my coding so far is PHP/CSS.

```
<a href="#logout">
<span>Logout</span>
<img src="images/logout.png" 
  onmouseover="this.src='images/logout_hover.png'" 
  onmouseout="this.src='images/logout.png'" />
</a>
```

Comment: wouldn't you add a class to the anchor tag (generated via php) that reflects if the user is logged in or not? Also, why use onmouseover and onmouseout? I haven't seen this used in years.

Comment: Also. If you use the way I mention above, you would put the image as a background image on the anchor itself and would not need the image tag at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since events propagate, this should work:

```
<a id="login_link" href="#logout" onmouseover="document.getElementById('login_image').src='images/logout_hover.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('login_image').src='images/logout.png'">
    <span>Logout</span>
    <img src="images/logout.png" id="login_image" />
</a>
```

But as [2pha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550696/2pha) mentioned, using simple CSS is a lot better:

```
#login_link span#logo_image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent url(images/logout.png) top left no-repeat;
}
#login_link:hover span#logo_image {
    background-image: url(images/logout_hover.png);
}
```

Or better yet, merge the 2 images and use the new image as a sprite, so they will preload together:

```
#login_link span#logo_image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent url(images/logout.png) top left no-repeat;
}
#login_link:hover span#logo_image {
    background-position: bottom left;
}
```